# Botpress: Custom Content Type and Custom Rendering

Tags: bots, chatbot

I am new to Botpress.

I just installed the latest version ‘botpress-ce-v11_0_1-win-x64’ of Botpress.
I was going over the documentation and i found some explanation about Content Type, Content Element and Content Rendering. But it is not very clear as to how I can create a custom type and it’s rendering.

Also reading further in the section ‘Creating Modules’ it says:
“and soon they will be able to add new content types and content elements”.

so, I am not able to clearly understand how can i create custom content type and it’s rendering that is specific to my domain.

I am trying to understand if I have to add custom elements like Radio Buttons or Checkboxes or Dropdowns in my response that is displayed in the web chat for instance, how can i achieve that.

I would highly appreciate if someone can provide some example or link to the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I can understand the [botpress docs](https://botpress.io/docs/) can be a pain, even I went through the same path and created a [blog](https://abhisheksimon.wordpress.com) to help others like me, as it's v12.0.6 and still there are many missing links in their document.

To answer your question yes you need to [create a custom component](https://abhisheksimon.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/how-to-create-a-custom-component-in-botpress/) for radio buttons, checkboxes (dropdown already exists), which requires you to [create a custom module](https://abhisheksimon.wordpress.com/2019/08/02/botpress-how-to-create-a-custom-module/).

Please go through the above mentioned links inline for an understanding and how to guide on each topic.